# Double Commander — switch between 1 and 2 (split) panels

Tags: double-commander

Given that the question is present on the forums ([here](https://doublecmd.sourceforge.io/forum/viewtopic.php?p=17638#p17638)) without a very clear answer needed by a new user, I'm posting this in order to provide that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As specified at the address linked in the question, the command to use is `cm_PanelsSplitterPerPos`. By itself, it sets a 50/50% 2-split view. But it takes parameters of the form `splitpct=100`, which will hide the *right* panel (show the left one), while `splitpct=0` will hide the *left* one (show the right one).

---

### **Adding toolbar buttons:**

Right-click on the toolbar, "Edit". Insert new button, Check "Internal command".

[image]

Click the Command field and select `cm_PanelsSplitterPerPos`.

Add `splitpct=100`, to the "Parameters" field for a button to hide the *right* panel and show only the left one, and `splitpct=0` for a button to hide the *left* panel and show only the right one. Leave the "Parameters" field empty for the button to revert to 2-panel default view.
Use the "Tooltip" field for a button description on mouse hover.

[image]

[image]

In the images above the icons used are those from [here](http://www.iconarchive.com/search?q=hide), slightly altered. In the end I made different ones to fit better the GUI.

[image]

Here they are:

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

### Adding shortcuts:

I have set F3 for defaulting to split view (no parameters), F4 for the `splitpct=0` parameter:

[image]

F5 for the `splitpct=100` parameter.

As said, use `splitpct=100` in the "Parameters" field for a shortkey to hide the *right* panel and show only the left one, and `splitpct=0` for a shortkey to hide the *left* panel and show only the right, while the command `cm_PanelsSplitterPerPos` without parameters is the default split-view..