# Double Commander — switch between 1 and 2 (split) panels with inconsistent toolbar height

Tags: double-commander

Follow the answer of [Double Commander — switch between 1 and 2 (split) panels](https://superuser.com/questions/1540333).
Very thanks for useful solution.
But I got inconsistent toolbar height in left-panel view.
I'm on win10 with 22H2 version.
[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRzqu.gif)

After some try I found that disable `show two drive button bars` may help.
But I want to know is there any better solution to keep current setting?
[setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uFx5.png)

left side window of below figure can see the height is unusual.
and display of right side window is what I expected.
[compare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgwu0.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ok, I add the expected result and comparison.